# Earth orbiting the Sun on java

Tags: java

When running the program 'NaN' values are printed. I've deduced the error lies in the my main class within the do while loop during the "Sun.componentY()" and "Sun.componentX()" part as new Grav Field divides by zero. To correct this I attempted to write a new method in by Gravfield called CalcAcc that works out the force between the sun and Earth. I am unsure however how to implement it to my main method using vectors and how to get it to work to output the position and velocity of the Earth correctly. Please see code below, many thanks in advance.

Just to clarify my simulation consists of 4 different classes my PhysicsVector class I believe is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Put your application here and paste link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about the error that occurs in `yVelocity += Sun.componentY() * timeStep;` -- is there a descriptive message?

Comment: Sun has a vector of (0,0), so `distance = 0`. This ends up in a `/0`. Pretty much basic debugging I'd say, no offence intended :)

Comment: There are dozens of errors in this code. Variables not used, `timeStep += timeStep;`. Please learn how to use a debugger and step through your code and inspect variables.

Comment: I understand where I'm going wrong however I just can't get it to work.

Comment: @IamThankful I don't think you do understand - gravity in space needs a different model to the fixed ~9.8m/s^2 vertically that we experience on earth.  The latter *can* be described with a "field" because it's locally constant (and dominated by the mass of earth itself) but it's not a good model for bodies in space.

Comment: more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field, some of which contradicts what I've said above, but a "proper" gravitational field model requires much more complicated mathematics than you've been describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GravField` seems like an unusual abstraction in this case.   In "simplified" physics engines you can have a gravity "field" that imparts a constant force on every object, much as you'd get on earth.

In this case however you're simulating space, and gravity is considered to be a distortion in space/time.  Every time an object moves it affects the forces on every other body.

I suggest you rethink that abstraction, and for every iteration of your engine just calculate the gravitational force between each combination of pairs of objects in your simulation.  This will be an O(n^2) operation!